# Select interaction shown visually outside layer extent

Tags: openlayers

I'm running with openlayers 4.3.1

When I add ol.interaction.Select to ol.Map, the most recent Select event is shown visually outside the layer extent

An example where a Select event is triggered when drawing a Point, and the location is shown outside the extent (but not drawn):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayGqdN?editors=1010

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to avoid it to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `wrapX` option into `ol.interaction.Select`
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html

as you set `wrapX:false` in your code, it means no-repeat for the target.

```
//vector source display with no repeat horizontally
var source = new ol.source.Vector({ wrapX: false });
```

simply add an option for `ol.interaction.Select`

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
  layers: [vector],
  wrapX: false
});
```